# DRF: How to get Users object in a get method as a Response?

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can I get all user objects in get method in views.py with other models?

views.py

```
class WebDashboardViews(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.DashboardSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_user_queryset = models.User.objects.all()
        if not all_user_queryset:
            total_user = 0
        else:
            total_user = all_user_queryset.count()
        total_android_user = models.UserMobileDevice.objects.filter(os="Android")
        if not total_android_user:
            total_android_count = 0
        else:
            total_android_count = total_android_user.count()
        content = {'total_user':total_user,'total_android_count':total_android_count, all_users: all_user_queryset}
        return Response(content)
```

I want the user object in all_users key. But I am getting an error:

> Object of type User is not JSON serializable

My serializer code is :

```
class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        field = ['id','created_at','name']
```

I am not sure what I am doing here. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you are trying to respond with not-serialized objects here: `all_users: all_user_queryset`

You need to serialize them first (I guess you have an `UserSerializer`, if don't, just rename your `DashboardSerializer` to `UserSerializer` because it is just what it is):

```
user_serializer = UserSerializer(all_user_queryset, many=True)
content = {'total_user':total_user,'total_android_count':total_android_count, all_users: user_serializer.data}
return Response(content)
```